# SCSS file doesn't see imported files

Tags: sass

I want to use `@import` in my scss file. It was working okay, but now I do `@import "vars";` (I have `_vars.scss` file in the same dir) and Prepros returns error saying such file doesn't exists. What is wrong?

style.scss:

```
body {
    background: white
}

@import "vars";
```

_vars.scss:

```
$grey: #777;
$violet: #490a3d;
$text: #414141;
$separator: #d6d8d8;
$title: #0d0d0d;
$white: #fff;
```

Comment: If you can't reproduce the error with Sass by itself, the problem is with Prepros.

Comment: Looks okay for sass. Maybe is a prepros problem? Try going on ruby command prompt, go to the sass folder and type `sass --watch style.scss:style.css` to see if sass itself does giver any error (considering you have ruby and sass gem installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Problem was with Prepros (too bad, it's a great piece of software). It turned out,my directory name was the cause of all this. It was named `[projects]`, since I keep there all my "temp" stuff. I moved the files to other directory and it works great.